# Making sub-menus exclusive

Tags: menus

I don't really know how to explain what I'm looking for so bare with me here.
On my site I have a side menu with a bunch of sub categories with a few items in each. I want to know if there's a way to close all the other open subcategories when I open another one, for example:

```
1. Animals

----A. Cats

----B. Dogs

2. People

----A. Samantha

----B. Daniel
```

When I press on "Animals" I want "People" to close and vice versa so that the menu is always:

```
1. Animals

----A. Cats

----B. Dogs

2. People

or

1. Animals

2. People

----A. Samantha

----B. Daniel
```

and not open all at once. I hope you guys understand what I'm looking for.

Comment: Code please....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm making some assumptions here, like you are the one writing the code for the theme, or at least have the ability to modify the JavaScript in some way.

You can accomplish this using jQuery using code along these lines:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.parent ul').slideUp();
    $('.parent > li > a').on('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var $this = $(this);
        $this.parent().siblings().find('ul').slideUp();
        $this.siblings('ul').slideDown();
    });
});
```